# More efficient way to format cells based on a given reference

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am creating a google sheet which contains fixtures and I would like to color all the cells featuring the fixtures which show how relatively easy/difficult the match is for a given team. [This is my spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xXhBzawF5KeUd1Xz94qH81xJI5akAFLevVQo5L4yeUY/edit?usp=sharing). The following is the code that I am currently using -

```
// Function to find the row number of a given fixture 

function findRow(empName){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  //var fix = ss.getSheetByName('Fixtures');
  var fdr = ss.getSheetByName('FDR');
  var data = fdr.getDataRange().getValues();
  for(var i = 0; i<data.length;i++){
    if(data[i][1] == empName){ //[1] because column E
      Logger.log((i+1))
      return i+1;
    }
  }
}

// Function to color the given cell based on its fixture difficulty

function colorMeUp() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var fix = ss.getSheetByName('Fixtures');
  var fdr = ss.getSheetByName('FDR');
  
  for(var i = 4; i <= 23; i = i + 1){
    for(var j = 3; j <= 40; j = j + 1){
      var temp = fix.getRange(i,j).getValue(); // Find the fixture to color
      var master = fix.getRange(i,2).getValue(); // Find the reference team
      var rowNumMaster = findRow(master);
      var rowNumTemp = findRow(temp);
      if(rowNumTemp < 23){
        rowNumMaster = rowNumMaster + 20;
      }
      var tempRating = fdr.getRange(rowNumTemp,4).getValue();
      var masterRating = fdr.getRange(rowNumMaster,4).getValue();
      var fixDiff = masterRating + (6-tempRating); // Calculate relative fixture difficulty
      var rang = fdr.getRange(1+fixDiff,8).getBackground();
      fix.getRange(i,j).setBackground(rang); 
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, this code uses the table given in the "FDR" sheet to assign a colour to each fixture given in the "Fixture" sheet. However, when I press the ugly blue button on the left side the process of it happening is painfully slow and it exceeded the maximum time. Is there any way to make this process go faster by tweaking this code/ using a different approach? I am very new to all this so don't really know what I can do to make this better/faster.

Answer (score 1):

Try integrating  `if(data[i][1] == empName){` column two of data into a flatten array and then you can use indexOf instead of call a function twice in the center of a loop.  So inotherword trash findRow and build it inside of colorMeUp

So something like this:

```
function colorMeUp() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var fix = ss.getSheetByName('Fixtures');
  var fdr = ss.getSheetByName('FDR');
  const sA = fdr.getRange(1,2,fdr.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues().flat();
  
  for(var i = 4; i <= 23; i = i + 1){
    for(var j = 3; j <= 40; j = j + 1){
      var temp = fix.getRange(i,j).getValue(); // Find the fixture to color
      var master = fix.getRange(i,2).getValue(); // Find the reference team
      var rowNumMaster = sA.indexOf(master) + 1
      var rowNumTemp = sA.indexOf(temp) + 1
      if(rowNumTemp < 23){
        rowNumMaster = rowNumMaster + 20;
      }
      var tempRating = fdr.getRange(rowNumTemp,4).getValue();
      var masterRating = fdr.getRange(rowNumMaster,4).getValue();
      var fixDiff = masterRating + (6-tempRating); // Calculate relative fixture difficulty
      var rang = fdr.getRange(1+fixDiff,8).getBackground();
      fix.getRange(i,j).setBackground(rang); 
    }
  }
}
```

I threw this together rather quickly so it may not actually work but it should speed things up considerably using that approach.  If you've done a few web apps then my guess is that you're a reasonable coder and should be able to integrate this into you code.  Or it's possible that I'm totally FOS.

It would be really good to get rid of the getValue() in the loop in lieu of getValues() outside of the loop and use array indices to access the same data .  Same with getbackground.  I'd need to see your data to figure that out.

BTW I don't follow links to spreadsheets so giving me access to data involves post tables.'